# How to return result from a function in Django html form?

Tags: python, django

Basically I have this form right here

```
<form method="POST" action=".">
   <input type="text" name="fcal" value="{{F}}" />
<p>
   <input type="submit" name="fibo" value="Fibonacci" />
</p>
</form>
```

I would like the user to input a number and after that this number to be calculated and printed in a Fibonacci sequence.

This is my Fibonacci function

```
def fibo(n):
    if n == 0:
       return 0
    elif n == 1:
       return 1
    else:
       result = fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)
       return result
```

I believe my problem is coming from the views.py file because I am not sure how to create the result to be rendered back.

```
from django.template import Context, loader, RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404, HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponseNotFound
import fibonacci


def fibocal(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       fb = request.POST['fcal']
       cal = fibonacci.fibo(fb)
       return render_to_response('fibb/fibb.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, cal))
    else:
       print('Wrond input type')
```

I would highly appreciate if someone can at least explain how to get the result from a function and print it out on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

your html file

```
    <form method="POST" action=".">
       <input type="text" name="fcal" value="{{F}}" />
    <p>
       <input type="submit" name="fibo" value="Fibonacci" />
    </p>
    </form>

{% if cal %}
      Your Fibonacci answer is {{cal}} 
{% endif %}
```

Your view:

```
def fibocal(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       fb = request.POST['fcal']
       cal = fibonacci.fibo(fb)
       return render(request, 'fibb/fibb.html', {'cal': cal})
    else:
       return render(request, 'fibb/fibb.html', {})
```

This will do the trick

Comment: Thanks for your response I've edit my code but right now the error which I have is: The view fibb.views.fibb didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.